# Django REST Framework and Backbone.js: how to avoid hard-coding URLs?

Tags: django, backbone.js

I'm using Django as a back-end REST API for a Backbone front-end application.

I don't want to hard-code urls for models and collections in Backbone scripts and duplicate them with Django. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: I normally add them as constants at the bottom of the HTML. Something like `<script>var CLIENT_URL = '{% url 'some-url-name' %}';</script>` and then reference `CLIENT_URL` in your models.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I like this decision. Probably, I should take it.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found an interesting lib for this - django-js-reverse. It provides a management command that takes your urls from django and generate js files with your urls and js function to reverse it in your js files. Take a look at it

https://github.com/ierror/django-js-reverse